# Using a join within a sub query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The following query is returning all `affiliate_id`'s where the amount owed is more than 50.

```
        SELECT
            t1.affiliate_id
        FROM
        (
            SELECT affiliate_id, SUM(payout) AS payout_total
            FROM exp_cdwd_aff_purchases
            GROUP BY affiliate_id
        ) t1
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT affiliate_id, SUM(amount_paid) AS amount_paid_total
            FROM exp_cdwd_aff_payments
            GROUP BY affiliate_id
        ) t2
            ON t1.affiliate_id = t2.affiliate_id
        WHERE t1.payout_total > COALESCE(t2.amount_paid_total, 0) + 50
```

I need to also return an email address for each `affiliate_id` from the table `exp_member_data`. The `affiliate_id` can be referenced against `member_id`.

I had thought the following may work, but it doesn't. Can anyone explain how I can get this result?

```
        SELECT
            t1.affiliate_id, t1.m_field_id_26
        FROM
        (
            SELECT af.affiliate_id, SUM(af.payout) AS payout_total, md.m_field_id_26
            FROM exp_cdwd_aff_purchasesAS af
            LEFT JOIN exp_member_data AS md.member_id = af.affiliate_id
            GROUP BY affiliate_id
        ) t1
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT affiliate_id, SUM(amount_paid) AS amount_paid_total
            FROM exp_cdwd_aff_payments
            GROUP BY affiliate_id
        ) t2
            ON t1.affiliate_id = t2.affiliate_id
        WHERE t1.payout_total > COALESCE(t2.amount_paid_total, 0) + 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your query correctly, then the easiest thing to do would be to just add another join to the end to bring in the email address.  Something like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.affiliate_id,
    COALESCE(t3.m_field_id_26, 'email is NA') AS m_field_id_26
FROM
(
    SELECT affiliate_id, SUM(payout) AS payout_total
    FROM exp_cdwd_aff_purchases
    GROUP BY affiliate_id
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT affiliate_id, SUM(amount_paid) AS amount_paid_total
    FROM exp_cdwd_aff_payments
    GROUP BY affiliate_id
) t2
    ON t1.affiliate_id = t2.affiliate_id
LEFT JOIN exp_member_data t3
    ON t1.affiliate_id = t3.member_id
WHERE t1.payout_total > COALESCE(t2.amount_paid_total, 0) + 50
```

Doing the join inside your aggregation query, as you currently have it, probably isn't ideal because that subquery exists to tally things, not to include email address information.